# Yarn MiniCluster unable to access /ws/v1/cluster/info

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I started a Yarn+HDFS single JVM process mini cluster by following the instructions on this page

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html

I can access /ws/v1/node/info  like this

`curl 127.0.0.1:8088/ws/v1/node/info 
{"nodeInfo":{"healthReport": ......}}`

But i cannot access /ws/v1/cluster/info,

`curl 127.0.0.1:8088/ws/v1/cluster/info`

```
<h1>
  Error Details
</h1>
<pre>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: /v1/cluster/info: controller for v1 not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Router.resolveDefault(Router.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Router.resolve(Router.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:134)
```

I also did a netstat -tnpl to list all listening sockets and tried accessing /ws/v1/cluster/info on all of them, but it doesn't work.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: I'm surprised that `/ws/v1/node/info` works because the documentation states that API would also be `/ws/v1/cluster/nodes/{nodeid}`